# How to wait for data in Python API Request

Tags: python, api, request, delay

I am using a Python script to query our wireless controllers (ArubaOS). They offer an API function called "showcommand" which let's you send any (perhaps not *any* but anyway) of the normal commands that you would type in at the CLI (often these are like "show ... some stuff", hence *show*command).

It normally does a good job of returning some structured data. However I am running a particular command which has an issue. When you run the command on the CLI it initially displays a warning like "This command may take some time to run, please be patient" and then it displays the actual data. When I run the command from my Python script all I get back is the warning, no actual useful data.

I can't think of a way to solve this. Maybe if there was a way to introduce a delay immediately after the request is made to wait for the data? But I guess that would need to be something within the requests module, and I can't see a likely candidate. Does anyone have any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: Have you explored if `stream=True` and/or  `chunk_size` helps?

Comment: That looks interesting thank you - new to me but I'll see if I can work it out...